# Non vanishing of a cohomology class associated to a nef vector bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, chern-classes

**Lemma.** Let $E$ be a rank $r$ *nef* vector bundle over a polarized smooth complex projective variety $(X,H)$ of dimension $n\leq r$. Then for any $t\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^nt^{n-k}\int_Xc_k(E)\cdot H^{n-k}\geq0.
$$
In particular $\displaystyle\int_Xc_n(E)\geq0$.

**Proof.** See Theorem 8.2.1 Lazarsfeld R. K. (2004) *Positivity in Algebraic Geometry, II. Positivity for Vector Bundles, and Multiplier Ideals*. Springer-Verlag

In the proof he defines $\xi_0=c_1(\mathcal{O}_E(1))+t_0\pi^{*}c_1(\mathcal{O}_X(H))\in H^2(\mathbb{P}(E),\mathbb{Z})$ for some (opportune) $t_0\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, where $\pi:\mathbb{P}(E)\to X$ is the canonical projection. He declares, without prove it, that the following cohomology class is non-zero:
$$
\beta=\xi_0^{n-1}-\pi^{*}a_1(t_0)\xi_0^{n-2}+\dotsc+(-1)^{n-1}\pi^{*}a_{n-1}(t_0)\in H^{2(n-1)}(\mathbb{P}(E),\mathbb{Z})
$$
where
$$
\forall t\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0},p\in\{1,\dotsc,n\},\,a_p(t)=\sum_{k=0}^p\binom{n-k}{p-k}t^{p-k}c_k(E)\cdot H^{p-k}
$$
**Question:** why is $\beta$ non-zero?

Comment: Apply the projection formula: $\pi _*\beta =\pi _*\xi _0^{n-1}=1$.

Comment: Ok, I thank you! I had thought to apply this formula, but I am not so pratice with it; and the books of Prof.s Fulton and Lazarsfeld are not so clear about it. Could you suggest me another reference?